# Building a microservices application on. Net?

Tags: .net, f#, microservices

I plan to build an internal application for my company and want to implement it in micro services. All the servers in my company is Windows servers.

I'm thinking build it using asp.net core, etc. Is there a good example available? What kind of tech stack it will need?

Comment: usually you could look at WCF, but im not aware of a WCF Core "server" only client part. And now WebAPI is gone in core (it is merged) so you could do regular ASP.NET Core with only controllers.

Comment: https://www.manning.com/books/microservices-in-net ?

Comment: If all your servers are Windows servers, then why go after core? .NET itself is pretty mature and well-known.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I want to use the .Net core because (1) I don't want to depend on the .Net framework on the server which may be old (2) Asp.Net core seem much faster.

Comment: You can try [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/) on .net

Answer (score 1):

> I....want to implement it in micro services

I would suggest that the decision to use microservices for a new application is often made without fully considering the premium you will pay in terms of up-front complexity.

This premium has two main components:

1. Cost associated with building a [microservice chassis](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservice-chassis.html)
2. Cost for greater up-front business domain analysis, to identify the natural [context boundaries](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) of your application.

The point being, even though your application will benefit from a microservice approach overall, it is rarely a good idea to start off with this approach.

See my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913794/569662) for more information.