# What is the difference between Azure API Apps and Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-api-apps

I am using Azure Table storage to store the data of my application. I need to build an API to retrieve the data from Azure table storage. There are like a million records in the table. In the initial stage, my API would be getting approximately 100-1000 hits per day. What would be the best choice to develop that API on, API apps or Service Fabric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a lot of aspects:

- How do you want to maintain it?
- What performance requirements do you have? Do all those 100-1000 hits per day happen at the same time or are they distributed across the day?
- How do you want to handle scaling?

[As described by @feranto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601764/1062217) the main difference is the architectural pattern. The decision will have a lot of implications for you, not only when it comes to development, but you will have to consider how to maintain your application.

Only based on your short description, it sounds like a relatively straightforward solution and not very complex nor very high performance/scale requirements. Given that, it might be easier for you to go for a more basic API App. Service Fabric is an excellent framework and architecture that allows us to build very flexible, highly scalable solutions, but it should be noted that that also comes with a lot more complexity when it comes to handling, monitoring and maintaining both the underlying service cluster and it's applications.

Setting up an API App, connecting to an Azure Storage table and control that with for instance [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) is relatively straight forward and you can find a lot of documentation and samples for that. As a contrast, Service Fabric is fairly nascent in documentation and samples, and you would have to read up on a lot to get a basic stable solution running if you are new to it.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `Azure API` and `Azure Service Fabric` is the architecture pattern each one follows:

- [`Azure API APPs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/api/) supports a monolithic architecture. You have all your code running as one single package. You can develop this using Java, PHP, nodejs, python or .net.
- [`Service Fabric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/) follows a microservice architecture. Every service is deployed on a separate node, which can scale independently, and you can monitor the health of every service in every node. You can develop this using Java or C# mainly.

[Here you can see advantages and disadvantages between microservices and a monolithic architecture.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041733/microservices-vs-monolithic-architecture)

Comment: `Api Apps` are the part of `Web Apps` which are running inside its own VM where you don't have basically access. `Service Fabric` allows you to control some infrastructure aspects of the cluster it's running on. Basically, these are 2 different levels/layers. You can run an ASP.NET Web Api app (using Owin) on top of Service Fabric. In Web/Api App it'll be IIS only.