# Where to call Azure Blob Storage APIs from - web app server side or azure function

Tags: api, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-for-containers

Is it better (best practice wise) to use the Azure Blob Storage APIs from an Azure Web App (server side code) or make the API calls from an Azure function.

I think using the functions way is better for 'separation of concerns', more maintainable - in that multiple apps could use the same azure function - one place instead of many, can be monitored from within Azure (metrics) and dashboard. During a data breach a function can be turned off without shutting down the web app. Are there other reasons to use the API from a function vs the Web App backend?

Thanks

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do.... If you are using SAS Token, you can also call the blob storage APi directly from the browser. It really depends on your scenario. There is no general rules. Can you be more specific on your scenario ?

Comment: It really boils down to whether you (and your team) are inclined to go with a monolithic (Web App) or microservice (Functions) architecture. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041733/microservices-vs-monolithic-architecture/33662057#33662057 is a good summary of the pros and cons.

Comment: "Which is better?" type questions are very subjective and the answers will be opinion based. Try being more specific and technical in your question if you are asking about Security, Microservices architecture, or some other topic area.