# Is it a good practice to bundle the react web application in spring boot instead of running as a separate micro service?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, saml-2.0, adfs

I am new to react and single sign on implementation as well. Tech stack of application is Spring boot, SAML , ADFS and React. After reading some the article we found of ADFS interaction through SPA is not a good choice. We can't move out of react at the same time. So though of bundle the react and Springboot application as single service instead of separate micro services.

Please let me know is this a good approach. I found some article related to this approach.

But, I am looking for a better way to achieve this.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-package-your-react-app-with-spring-boot-41432be974bc

Comment: Your question is [Microservices vs Monolithic Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041733/microservices-vs-monolithic-architecture), could you provide more information about the use case?

Comment: The biggest thing that I can say is that the SAML response should not be validated on client hardware. It should be validated server-side, with identity tokenized somehow (OIDC maybe).